# After a compiz traditional crash my top toolbar disappeared. What can I do now?

Tags: compiz

At this moment my Compiz crashed, and the top bar disappeared, as also Alt + Tab, or the left launcher.
So I cant open a terminal (with ctrl+t), or change program that I am using. Im locked into firefox and cant open, reboot or logoff (only on the power button).
What can I do?

PS: After I upgraded from 11 to 12.04 my ubuntu is always crashing, lagging more, etc.

Comment: Magic combinations to your rescue. Alt+Printscr+K should mercilessly kill everything and get you back to login screen.

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1:

Switch to a tty, and do some geeky debugging.
Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd> switches to `tty1` through `tty6` respectively. A `tty` is a virtual terminal. log in to your account, and in case of a crash, [submit a bug report.](https://askubuntu.com/a/137915/45659) <sub>(Answer by Me)</sub>

- To restart Graphical User Interface - `sudo service lightdm restart`

  This will log you out in GUI and gets you back to login screen. If you use a non-default display manager, replace `lightdm` with `kdm` or `gdm` as appropriate.
- In most cases, restarting unity should work. `unity --replace`

  This will restart just Unity. Any open applications will remain open, and is hence safe and better to try this before restarting DM. If the command exits with `137`; retry it. It works. If the command exits with `1`, Retrying it will have no effect. It will continue to fail.

  > Remember to switch to graphical console on tty7 after running this. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> )

### Option 2:

The magic SysRsq combinations are guaranteed to work. there are a whole lot of them, and googling may help.

For now, we are particularly interested in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScr</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, which kills all processes on a tty, so while on `tty7` ( the default one with graphics) it kills Xserver and brings you back to login screen.

Comment: what if `unity --replace` doesn't terminate at all?

Answer (score 0):

The old CTRL-ALT+1 opens a text terminal.

From there you can troubleshout or simply issue a shutdown command.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to terminal number 1 (`control`+`alt`+`F1`) and run

```
DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace
```

or

```
DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace
```

Sometimes it doesn't restart; Just kill all compiz processes and try again in case.

Comment: `compiz` [supports the `--display` flag](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/compiz.1.html). So those prefer can run `compiz --display :0 --replace` instead of `DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace`.