# Ubuntu 16.04 regular crash, Compiz segfault, error 4 in i965_dri.so, Fresh install

Tags: 14.04, compiz

Not that familiar with bug reports but I tried searching https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/ for this error without success. Maybe you can help me identify if this is a duplicate of an existing bug or if a known solution exists. My question build on this previous question [After a compiz traditional crash my top toolbar disappeared. What can I do now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151267/after-a-compiz-traditional-crash-my-top-toolbar-disappeared-what-can-i-do-now) that never received a solution.

My symptoms are similar but not the same, when hovering over or clicking menu button in Ubuntu 16.04, all open windows and menus crash and reappear again after a while. Same effect if I press the `home` button on my keyboard to open the menu. Also happens when I click Shutdown or Suspend from the top menu. This does not affect all menu items however, I am still able to open Firefox and the File Explorer from the menu. Shortcuts also work (ctrl+alt+T) and tty sessions (ctrl+alt+1-6).

Is this error the same as this perhaps? [GUI/Unity crashing in 16.04 LTS after latest updates, compiz segfaults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-latest-updates-compiz-segfaults). Although My windows reappear again and as long as I use shortcuts and avoid alt-tab I can use my laptop.

An extract from syslog tells me this:

```
Jan  6 15:15:33 mofs kernel: [ 1294.824998] compiz[3930]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f6b31519c16 sp 00007ffc35380cc0 error 4 in i965_dri.so[7f6b30f3c000+82d000]
Jan  6 15:15:38 mofs gnome-session[1590]: ** (unity-fallback-mount-helper:1803): WARNING **: Can't call IsLocked() on the Unity.Session object: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'com.canonical.Unity.Session' on object at path /com/canonical/Unity/Session
```

every new crash creates a new kernel segfault. The gnome warning line occurs sporadically.

I have tried installing Ubuntu fresh again from a USB image but after `sudo apt-get update` and `upgrade` it started happening again. 
I have also tried reinstalling compiz to no effect.

This bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nux/+bug/1311503 seemed promising although my screen does not turn blue, and I tried reinstalling `libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0` to no effect.

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

**Update:**
**This issue is best reported and updated here [GUI/Unity crashing in 16.04 LTS after latest updates, compiz segfaults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-latest-updates-compiz-segfaults?noredirect=1&lq=1) . It also provides workaround solutions until a bug fix is issued**

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/992353/ubuntu-16-04-jan-3-2018-update-causing-screen-access-issues

Comment: Yep, seems like the same error. Should I delete my question?

Comment: Normally I'd say yes but yours contains different information and this is a fast developing bug with reports flowing in regularly. Others will mark it as a duplicate later if the same solution to all these problems exist.