# Samsung notebook spin 7 with ubuntu 18.04 keyboard backlight problem

Tags: keyboard, samsung, backlight

I have samsung notebook 7 spin laptop with ubuntu 18.04 installed on it. I am not been able to turn on the keyboard backlight atleast not by using the dedicated function key. Please help I'm new to ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check these posts

- [Cannot turn on keyboard backlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644410/cannot-turn-on-keyboard-backlight)
- [How to automate keyboard backlight on at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993311/how-to-automate-keyboard-backlight-on-at-boot)

Mostly running this command on terminal works:

```
xset led on
```

or

```
xset led 3
```

Comment: Still stucked :( NOT WORKING

Comment: If you don't give us more details, we can't help you.